# How to add a color gradient line(collection) to the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Unfortunately, there is currently no simple way to create a gradient colored line in `matplotlib`. [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19877666/5472354), there are plenty of nice solutions to this problem, but they essentially all rely on using `LineCollections` (or `pcolormesh`, however such an artist is not supported by the legend). In and of itself, this is not a problem, but if you add the `LineCollection` to the legend, its key will only have a single color, instead of a gradient (e.g. using [unutbu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941474/5472354) as an example here):

[image]

Now I know you can create a custom handler, e.g. as explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler), but I have no idea how to do this for such a case. If I look at the source code of the [`HandlerLineCollection`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.2/lib/matplotlib/legend_handler.py#L418-L447) (which I thought would be an obvious starting point to figure out how to modify it) I noticed that it is based on `Line2D`, which cannot handle color gradients. So I don't know how to proceed from here.

How can I add a color gradient line to the legend, where its key shows (at least part of) the lines color gradient as well?

Comment: Potentially this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49224137/5851928)?

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I didn't manage to find that post. I'll have a look!

Comment: @DavidG ok, awesome, that did the trick. Thanks!